Jetcd watcher cannot reconnect when etcd leader down or etcd cluster loses its quorum and comes back
I am using jetcd library for connecting to etcd in Java 8. I was trying a reconnecting mechanism whenever etcd goes down. We have 3 etcd pod cluster where we follow leader follower mechanism. When the etcd pod goes down where watcher is connected, the listener throws the exception asynchronously and there i am calling the same function to retry connecting watcher. The code works fine when a follower goes down that is watch is able to reconnect to available etcd pods. But when the leader etcd pod goes down or the etcd cluster loses quorum, the function keeps on retrying but is never able to reconnect. Please let me know how to fix this issue. Please find the code below.
public void watchAndListen(HandlerWrapper<JsonObject> handler) {

    Watch.Listener listen = Watch.listener(watchHandler(handler),

        throwable -> {

          System.out.println("Exception in watch"+ throwable.getCause());

          if (throwable instanceof EtcdException) {

            // Retry mechanism

            watchAndListen(handler);

          }

        });

    Watch watchClient = etcdClient.getWatchClient();

    watchClient.watch(storeKey, listen);

  }

I tried closing the Jetcd client and then create new one. This was able to fix the issue but i was getting RejectedExecutionException.
I tried creating ExecutorService manually to build the client, but got the same exception.
